# Self Referencing list item count from parent to to last child

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-2.1

i have a self referencing list of categories , where each category have list of children and in the same time have a list of items . 
example category1 (has 3 items, has 1 children subcategory )
          subcategory (has 1 item,has parent category1, has no children )
when i fetch the list of categories i included the item count , so i am expecting to get with category1 ( itemcount = 4 ) but what i am getting is 3

```
public class Category {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and below is the dto

```
public class CategoryForReturnDto
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ItemsCount { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

and finaly the automapper

```
        CreateMap<Category, CategoryForReturnDto> ()
            .ForMember (dest => dest.ItemsCount, opt => {
                opt.MapFrom (src => src.Items.Count);
            });
```

the item model is

```
public class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

DB example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to add a function

```
    static int RecursiveItemsCount (Category cat, int count) {
        count += cat.Items.Count ();
        foreach (var child in cat.Children) {
            count += RecursiveItemsCount (child, 0);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

and inside the automapper

```
        CreateMap<Category, CategoryForReturnDto> ()
            .ForMember (dest => dest.ItemsCount, opt => {
                int number = 0;
                opt.ResolveUsing (src => {
                    return RecursiveItemsCount (src, number);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You say yourself

> example category1 (has 3 items, has 1 children subcategory )

so ItemCount correctly returns 3. That's exactly what you're telling it to return:

```
opt.MapFrom (src => src.Items.Count);
```

I don't see any collection or property in the DTO for SubCategories; until you get them included, you can't get the number you want. (I'm not sure what you would call the number you want; ItemCount is misleading.)

Comment: yes 100% , i am trying to fix my code to be able to get the whole count not just the category item count

Comment: Your question says that Categories and Items are different. I assume that there is a category hierarchy (e.g. Category 'Skiiers' has a sub-category 'Female Skiiers') and items belonging to that category (e.g. Mikaela Shiffren) which are not themselves categories. If this is wrong, please expand your question to include what an Item is vs what a Category is.

Comment: example extented with item model and database example